# How to use ValueProviders to assign table and columns for SpannerIO at runtime?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I have a use case where in I have to pick up selected data from a spanner table and dump to BigQuery.

The catch here is that for the batch job the name of the table and the columns to select will only be known at runtime.

It seems that dataflow's `SpannerIO` doesn't accept the table and the columns at runtime. Please refer below code for better understanding:

```
p.apply(SpannerIO.read().withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig)
                .withTable("tablename")
                .withColumns(list or array of columns))
```

It only accepts string and not `ValueProviders`. How to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

To access runtime values you need to use the `ReadAll` transform and build an instance of `ReadOperation` in the previous step.

See [Reading data from all available tables](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector#reading_data_from_all_available_tables) from the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the withColumn and withTable methods of SpannerIO.Read do not take in a ValueProvider by default.

Could you write code outside your function to get the table and column names and then pass them into withTable and withColumn as a list of strings at runtime?

If they can be passed in as commandline arguments, consider using [PipelineOptions](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#configuring-pipeline-options).

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/dataflow/spanner-io/src/main/java/com/example/dataflow/SpannerReadApi.java#L58) is a simple example. More docs on using dataflow connectors from Cloud Spanner can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector).

Comment: No I won't be able to do that because I'm going to create a template of my code and I won't be able to use the run-time values directly as strings.

Comment: Are you trying to pass in the table name and column names as runtime parameters to your template?
Here is an example template for exporting a spanner database:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportPipeline.java

Comment: This will export all tables from the provided database to GCS as Avro Files. As I have stated in my problem statement, I need to pick up "selected data" not even the entire table whose name is given at runtime and dump that data to BigQuery not a file.

Answer (score 1):

I used read operation as suggested by Mairbek

```java
p.apply(Create.ofProvider(options.getMyParamValueProvider(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
        .apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<String, ReadOperation>() {
          @Override
          public ReadOperation apply(String value) {
            return ReadOperation.create()
                .withTable("TableName").withColumns(value);
          }
        }))
        .apply(SpannerIO.readAll().withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig));
```